# Can't create subclass into a loaded owl file

Tags: python-3.x, owlready

I have an owl/rdf file ontology, loaded it with owlready2 and want to create a subclass in a specific class in the ontology.

I've tried the code in the owlready2 documentation https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/class.html but shows me the issue: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

types.new_class(class_name, (self.onto[superclass]))